# How do I create two Java Spring service beans in which method parameters are being validated

Tags: spring, validation, service, proxy

If I have one specific Java service and I want to validate service method parameters (before the method is invocated) I simply annotate the service class with @Service and @Validated and the method parameters with one or more constraint annotations.

What do I have to do to create two services of the same class in which service method parameters are being validated?

The creation of two services can be done by adding two @Bean annotated methods (that return a service instance) in the configuration class. But this did not result in proxy classes and service method arguments where not validated.

Annotating the service producing method with @Bean and @Validated did not work.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own proxy using [`ProxyFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-prog):

```java
    @Bean
    public FooService fooService(Validator validator) {
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(new FooService());
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(new MethodValidationInterceptor(validator));

        // generated proxy; it can be casted to FooService
        Object proxy = proxyFactory.getProxy();

        return (FooService) proxy;
    }
```

---

It's weird though that your instances have not been wrapped into proxy. This should happen even when using `@Bean` configuration methods. You can try to debug `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory#initializeBean` (around the line with applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization).